# ¿Por qué no se me separan los Divs? Me aparecen muy pegados

Tags: php, html, css

Estoy trabajando en un PHP con MySQL de la presentación de un equipo de futbol.

Separo cada equipo por posición con un div que se llama cajajugador.

He hecho que funcione pero los divs entre una caja y otra estan muy pegados y con `<br/>` no se separan. Probé con `<p>&nsbp .</p>`, pero ademas de ser un churro, tampoco funciona bien. ¿Cómo lo hacen ustedes?.

Este es mi código:

```
     <html lang="es">
    introducir el código aquí

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/estilo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/laliga.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php /*if( isset($_POST['codEquipo']) ) { // Existe valorOpcion, es la variable que viene del ajax
    $codigo = $_POST['codEquipo'];// meto la variable en una variable php*/
$codigo = 1;
if( isset($codigo) ) {
    include("modulos/conexion.php");
    // selecionamos la base de datos
    if (mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname) === TRUE) {
    ?>
    <p>&nbsp &nbsp.</p> <!--lo uso para hacer el salto de linea -->

        <div class="titequipo">
            <span>&nbsp Entrenador</span>
        </div>
        <?php
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM entrenadores WHERE $codigo = ident";

        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

        if ($result2) {
            // Si hay registros
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) !== 0) {

                while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                    $escudo = $fila['ident'];
                    include ('modulos/buscarEscudo.php');
                    ?>
                    <div class="popupEntrenador" >
                        <div class="popCaja1">
                            <span>&nbsp Entrenador</span><img src="<?php echo $escudo; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="popcaja2">
                            <img src="<?php echo $fila['imagen']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="popCaja3">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Nombre:</b></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Nacido el:</b> </td>
                                    <td><?php echo $fila['fechanac']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b>Lugar:</b> </td>
                                    <td><?php echo $fila['lugarnac']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cajaJugadores">
                        <a href="#" class="entrenador" ><img src="<?php echo $fila['imagen']; ?>"></a><br>
                        <p><?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?></p>

                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        }




        $sql = "SELECT * FROM jugadores WHERE $codigo = idequipo ORDER BY posicion ASC ";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if ($result) {
// Si hay registros
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 0) {
                $def=0;
                $c=0;
                $del=0;
                while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                    switch ($fila['posicion']){
                        case 1:
                            $portero = array ($fila['nombrejug'],$fila['dorsal'],$fila['posicion'],
                                $fila['nacimiento'],$fila['lugarNacimiento'],$fila['altura'],
                                $fila['peso'], $fila['imagen']);

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $defensa[$def] = array ($fila['nombrejug'],$fila['dorsal'],$fila['posicion'],
                                $fila['nacimiento'],$fila['lugarNacimiento'],$fila['altura'],
                                $fila['peso'], $fila['imagen']);

                            $def++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $centro[$c] = array ($fila['nombrejug'],$fila['dorsal'],$fila['posicion'],
                                $fila['nacimiento'],$fila['lugarNacimiento'],$fila['altura'],
                                $fila['peso'], $fila['imagen']);

                            $c++;
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            $delantero[$del] = array ($fila['nombrejug'],$fila['dorsal'],$fila['posicion'],
                                $fila['nacimiento'],$fila['lugarNacimiento'],$fila['altura'],
                                $fila['peso'], $fila['imagen']);

                            $del++;
                            break;
                    }




                }
            ?>
                <p>&nbsp &nbsp.</p> <p>&nbsp &nbsp.</p> <!--lo uso para hacer el salto de linea -->
                <div class="titequipo">

                    <span>&nbsp Jugadores</span>

                </div>
                <div class="cajaJugadores">


                    <a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="<?php echo $portero[7]; ?>"></a><br>
                    <p><?php echo $portero[0]; ?></p>

                </div>
                <div class="cajaJugadores">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($defensa as $value) {

                                ?>

                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana" ><img src="<?php echo $value[7]; ?>"></a></td>

                                <?php


                            }
                            ?>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($defensa as $value) {

                                ?>


                                <td style="padding: 0;"><?php echo $value[0]; ?></td>
                                <?php


                            }
                            ?>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="cajaJugadores">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($centro as $value) {

                                ?>

                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana" ><img src="<?php echo $value[7]; ?>"></a></td>

                                <?php


                            }
                            ?>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($centro as $value) {

                                ?>


                                <td style="padding: 0;"><?php echo $value[0]; ?></td>
                                <?php


                            }
                            ?>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="cajaJugadores">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($delantero as $value) {

                                ?>

                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana" ><img src="<?php echo $value[7]; ?>"></a></td>

                                <?php


                            }
                            ?>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($delantero as $value) {

                                ?>


                                <td style="padding: 0;"><?php echo $value[0]; ?></td>
                                <?php


                            }
                            ?>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>



<?php
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Este sería el CSS:

```
      div.titequipo  {
     position: relative;
     top: 20px;
     left: 13px;
     width: 600px;
     height: 35px;
     float: left;
     text-align: left;
     border-radius: 20px;
     background-color:#336666;
     font-size: 35px;
 }
div.cajaEntrenador {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 25px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;

    border: solid 3px greenyellow;
}
div.cajaEntrenador p{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
div.cajaEntrenador img{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    border: solid 5px #336666;
}
div.cajajugadores {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 120px;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    border: solid 3px greenyellow;
}
div.cajajugadores p{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
div.cajajugadores img{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    border: solid 5px #336666;
}
div.cajajugadores table {
    position: relative;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;

}
div.cajajugadores table tr {



    text-align: center;

}
div.cajajugadores table td {

    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-align: center;

    width: 80px;

}
```

Codigo HTML una vez generada la web:

```
    <html lang="es">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/estilo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/02978B9B-0ED5-F343-B86A-20756DCD6086/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/laliga.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="cajaEquipo">
        <p>&nbsp &nbsp.</p>
        <!--lo uso para hacer el salto de linea -->
        <section>
        <div class="titequipo">
            <span>&nbsp Entrenador</span>
        </div>

            <div class="popupEntrenador">
                <div class="popCaja1">
                    <span>&nbsp Entrenador</span><img src="img/escudos/1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="popcaja2">
                    <img src="img/entrenadores/1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="popCaja3">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Nombre:</b></td>
                            <td>
                                Zinedine Zidane                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Nacido el:</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                1972-06-23                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Lugar:</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                Marsella(Francia)                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cajaEntrenador">
                <a href="#" class="entrenador"><img src="img/entrenadores/1.jpg"></a>
                <br>
                <p>
                    Zinedine Zidane                </p>

            </div>
                    </section>
                <p>&nbsp &nbsp.</p>
                <p>&nbsp &nbsp.</p>
                <!--lo uso para hacer el salto de linea -->
                <div class="titequipo">

                    <span>&nbsp Jugadores</span>

                </div>
                <div class="cajaJugadores">


                    <a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Keylornavas.jpg"></a>
                    <br>
                    <p>
                        Keylor Navas                    </p>

                </div>
                <div class="cajaJugadores">
                    <table>
                        <tr>

                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Sergioramos.jpg"></a></td>


                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Varane.jpg"></a></td>


                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Marcelo.jpg"></a></td>

                                                        </tr>
                        <tr>


                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    Sergio Ramos                                </td>


                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    Varane                                </td>


                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    Marcelo                                </td>
                                                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="cajaJugadores">
                    <table>
                        <tr>

                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Isco.jpg"></a></td>


                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Jamesrodriguez.jpg"></a></td>


                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Casemiro.jpg"></a></td>


                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Tonikroos.jpg"></a></td>

                                                        </tr>
                        <tr>


                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    Isco                                </td>


                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    James Rodriguez                                </td>


                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    Casemiro                                </td>


                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    Toni Kroos                                </td>
                                                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="cajaJugadores">
                    <table>
                        <tr>

                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Karenbenzema.jpg"></a></td>


                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Cristianoronaldo.jpg"></a></td>


                                <td><a href="#" class="ventana"><img src="img/jugadores/Bale.jpg"></a></td>

                                                        </tr>
                        <tr>


                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    Karen Benzema                                </td>


                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    Cristiano Ronaldo                                </td>


                                <td style="padding: 0;">
                                    Bale                                </td>
                                                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: puedes poner el codigo html una vez generada la web? para poder ver tu resultado. Un saludo

Comment: Tienes un archivo css asociado? Si es asi deberías incluirlo, sino la respuesta es usando css para dar formato, juegas con el tamaño de los contenedores y con las propiedades margin y padding. Haz una prueba y consulta en base a los resultados sino obtienes lo que esperas.

Comment: @lois6b @ Carmen Agregado el codigo HTML generado por la web y el css asociado. gracias

Comment: nótese que en mi edición te añadí tildes, así como formato, etc. No entiendo por qué eliminaste la tilde de _ademas_ y _estan_. https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/80004/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buda he aplicado algunas clases de css sobre parte de tu código para que quede más centrado y separado. Se trata de que los espacios y márgenes los aporte la hoja de estilos `css` y no el `código html`, es un código más limpio. Espero que se aproxime a lo que necesitas.

Una forma muy fácil de hacer pruebas es usando las `herramientas para desarrolladores` de los navegadores, como Chrome, que te permiten modificar las propiedades css de tu archivo de forma visual en la página que estás desarrollando, de modo que puedes ver como queda el aspecto antes de cambiar el código, sin necesidad de guardar y volver a cargar la página. Te recomiendo que lo pruebes si no lo has usado.

Código html:

```
<body>
    <div class="cajaEquipo">
        <section>
            <div class="titequipo mt20">
                <span>Entrenador</span>
            </div>
            <div class="popupEntrenador mr10">
                <div class="popCaja1 mt20">
                    <span>Entrenador</span><img src="img/escudos/1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="popcaja2">
                    <img src="img/entrenadores/1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="popCaja3">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Nombre:</b></td>
                            <td>
                                Zinedine Zidane                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Nacido el:</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                1972-06-23                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Lugar:</b> </td>
                            <td>
                                Marsella(Francia)                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cajaEntrenador mt20 mr10">
                <a href="#" class="entrenador"><img src="img/entrenadores/1.jpg"></a>
                <br>
                <p>
                    Zinedine Zidane                </p>

            </div>
        </section>        
    </div>
</body>
```

Código css:

```
<style>
.mt20 {margin-top: 20px;}
.mr10 {margin-left: 10px;}
.popupEntrenador div, .cajaEntrenador {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.popCaja1 img{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
}


div.titequipo  {
     width: 600px;
     height: 35px;
    /* float: left;*/
     text-align: left;
     border-radius: 20px;
     background-color:#336666;
     font-size: 35px;
     /*añadidos*/
     padding: 5px 30px;
 }
div.cajaEntrenador {
    color: white;
   /* position: relative;
    float: left;*/
    top: 25px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;

    border: solid 3px greenyellow;
}
div.cajaEntrenador p{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
div.cajaEntrenador img{
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 80px;
    border: solid 5px #336666;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Deberías utilizar estilos css para eso.

Para espaciar el contenido de varios elementos puedes jugar con los valores de `border`, `padding` y `margin`:

```css
p {
  padding: 10px;
}
div{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #9999ff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px;
}

.jugador{
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Divs sin separar</p>
<div>Jugador 1</div>
<div>Jugador 2</div>
<div>Jugador 3</div>

<p>Divs espaciados</p>
<div class="jugador">Jugador 1</div>
<div class="jugador">Jugador 2</div>
<div class="jugador">Jugador 3</div>
```